How to deploy simple react app to Azure App Service thorugh VS code
I create a simple create app with npx create-react-app frontend
I m trying to deploy this to the Azure App Service, through vs code. It is showing successfully deployed but when trying accessing the webApp it is showing error like
:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.
how to fix this

can you share you're github repo?

Can you provide the detailed error logs from Azure App Service?

In which operating system you're deploying you're app linux or windows?

thats error is resolved
now the problem is i m trying to deploy one spring boot application on the azure web app with runtime stack as java 17 which will serve the react application
but after deployment i m getting error like HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

if you have a new issue, can you post it as a new question with detailed error messages and code

https://github.com/sanjayprasadF5/springwithreact
here is the github repo

The provided link is not available, please reshare your repository link.

https://github.com/sanjayprasadF5/ReactAndSpringBoot
please try this link
i m having different issue that one is resolved.
Here i m try to package react inside springboot app only issue after deployment on azure web app it is showing issue

I have provided the steps to deploy your application in the answer, please check.


Here i m try to package react inside springboot app only issue after deployment on azure web app it is showing issue

You can deploy your SpringBoot+React application to Azure App Service using visual studio.
Follow below steps:

Run these commands to run the application locally and generate the jar/war file.

mvn clean install
mvn spring-boot:run

local response:

It generates the jar file under backend=>target folder.

Open the project in VSCode, right click on the jar file and select Deploy to Web App.



I could deploy your application to Azure App Service.


Deployment Logs:
10:22:50 AM kpswebapp: Starting deployment...
10:22:50 AM kpswebapp: Creating zip package...
10:23:57 AM kpswebapp: Zip package size: 18.4 MB
10:24:08 AM kpswebapp: Fetching changes.
10:24:09 AM kpswebapp: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/5e0ec665-89ca-48bb-a9c5-512ef025f81c.zip (17.59 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
10:24:52 AM: Error: The operation was aborted.
10:32:33 AM kpswebapp: Starting deployment...
10:32:33 AM kpswebapp: Creating zip package...
10:33:39 AM kpswebapp: Zip package size: 18.4 MB
10:33:40 AM kpswebapp: Fetching changes.
10:33:41 AM kpswebapp: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/a4942c2f-4479-426c-99b5-6c46b462f730.zip (17.59 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
10:33:44 AM kpswebapp: Updating submodules.
10:33:45 AM kpswebapp: Preparing deployment for commit id '9ec5a52e-3'.
10:33:45 AM kpswebapp: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
10:33:45 AM kpswebapp: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Generating deployment script.
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools" --basic --sitePath "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted"').
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Running deployment command...
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Kudu sync from: '/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Finished successfully.
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Running post deployment command(s)...
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
10:33:46 AM kpswebapp: Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip.
10:34:01 AM: Deployment to "kpswebapp" completed.

Portal:


Hi Thanks for reply I m able to deploy so only thing is in the target folder i m not able to see the backed-0.0.1- Snapshot.jar So i directly deploy entire folder it worked for me now the issue is I want default authentication enable for this so i added Identity provider in the WebApp from that it stop workingi Do you have any idea how to implement authentication here for my project

Check this MSDOC to configure the authentication.

I have implement the authentication as mention in the documentation
but i m getting error like HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
in network tab
GET https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/ 400 (Bad Request)

Please raise a new question for authentication issue with all the required information and detailed errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78571650/springboot-authentication-failed-showing-localhost-refused-to-connect
here is the next question and github link for this
https://github.com/sanjayprasadF5/springapplication
